# MacOS shell creating a file containing a json

Tags: json, macos, shell, file, terminal

I have the following json:

```json
{
  "attributes": {},
  "children": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "ignoreBoundsFiltering": "false"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "text": "",
            "accessibilityText" : "Azione sull'account richiesta",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Through the shell I have to create a file with the following text using the following syntax: `echo '....' > k.json`

```json
echo "
{
  "attributes": {},
  "children": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "ignoreBoundsFiltering": "false"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "text": "",
            "accessibilityText" : "Azione sull'account richiesta",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
" > k.json
```

I've tried using the slash ( \ ) with both single and double quotes, but I'm not succeeding.

The problem that the json contains:

- Single quote in a label so I can't use single quote.
- Lots of double quotes therefore causing problems.

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

Comment: The json file contains double quotes, but no single quotes, and you don't want any substitutions to occur in the json text. The simplest solution would be to use single quotes for your `echo` instead of double quotes.

Comment: I see fancy non-ASCII smart quotes being used to mark a string in that JSON, making it invalid...

Comment: @user1934428 There's a single quote in it.

Comment: @user1934428: If you look at the image where the cursor is on that line there is a single quote as a string.

Comment: @Shawn: I don't understand, how would you solve the problem? You can give an example.

Comment: Ah, now I see the single quote. Still, I recommend to use single quotes for the `echo` and put a backslash in front of the single quote which is inside json. Also, as Shawn pointed out, have a look at the file with a hex editor: Do the quotes inside the text really have the correct ASCII code?

Comment: @user1934428: Can you give a working example because even putting the backslash doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question, to show the version with the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to hold the JSON literal:

```bash
cat > k.json <<'EOJ'
{
  "attributes": {},
  "children": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "ignoreBoundsFiltering": false
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "text": "",
            "accessibilityText": "Azione sull'account richiesta"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOJ
```

(Note fixing the smart quotes in the `"text": “”` field, and a trailing comma after the last field in an object; what you have in your question is not valid JSON).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `jq` installed, and you need to validate the json, then :

```
jq . > k.json <<'EOJ'
{
  "attributes": {},
  "children": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "ignoreBoundsFiltering": false
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "text": "",
            "accessibilityText": "Azione sull'account richiesta"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOJ
```